# Log4j2 JPAAppender blob

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, log4j2

after 2 days fighting with log4j2, hibernate and spring I finally got JPAAppender to work.. sort of..

I followed this example: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#JPAAppender

The class in the example creates a table with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `applicationLog` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `wrappedEvent` tinyblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

First issue was that I couldn't log anything because tinyblob is just too small. I fixed this manually by changing tinyblob into largeblob.

First question: is there a way to make the class extending BasicLogEventEntity to create a largeblob on its own?

Second question: how do I read the wrappedEvent using a mysql client? How do I get the logs' plain text out of the blobs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I changed the entity as follow, now the blob in the db is always empty (I don't need it anymore) and the other columns get populated with readable informations. It's just a workaround, but it's the best I could come up with...

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jpa.BasicLogEventEntity;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

/**
 *
 * @author syco
 */
@Entity(name = "applicationLog")
@Table(name = "`applicationLog`")
public class ApplicationLog extends BasicLogEventEntity {

  @Getter
  @Setter
  @Column(name = "`customEventDate`")
  private LocalDateTime customEventDate;

  @Getter
  @Setter
  @Column(name = "`customException`")
  @Type(type = "text")
  private String customException;

  @Getter
  @Setter
  @Column(name = "`customLevel`", length = 512)
  private String customLevel;

  @Getter
  @Setter
  @Column(name = "`customLogger`", length = 512)
  private String customLogger;

  @Getter
  @Setter
  @Column(name = "`customMessage`")
  @Type(type = "text")
  private String customMessage;

  @Getter
  @Setter
  @Column(name = "`customThreadName`", length = 512)
  private String customThreadName;

  @Getter
  @Setter
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "`id`")
  private long id;

  public ApplicationLog() {
    super();
  }

  public ApplicationLog(LogEvent logEvent) {
    super();
    if (logEvent != null) {
      setCustomEventDate(Instant.ofEpochMilli(logEvent.getTimeMillis()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime());
      if (logEvent.getThrown() != null) {
        setCustomException(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(logEvent.getThrown()));
      }
      if (logEvent.getLevel() != null) {
        setCustomLevel(logEvent.getLevel().name());
      }
      setCustomLogger(logEvent.getLoggerName());
      if (logEvent.getMessage() != null) {
        setCustomMessage(logEvent.getMessage().toString());
      }
      setCustomThreadName(logEvent.getThreadName());
    }
  }
}
```